# EF Core 2.0 relationships

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF Core, i need some help creating relationship. Currently i have 3 models.

Question Model

```
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }        
}
```

[Question data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbyhb.png)

Answer Model

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
}
```

[Answer Country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo46p.png)
[Answer State/Province](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xAIe.png)

CountryState Model

```
public class CountryState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
}
```

[CountryStates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I940.png)

The relationship between Question and Answer is already setup. But if i need to pull all provinces for Canada. I'm not sure how to setup relationships or if it's even possible.

In SQL i would use join

```
SELECT A.* FROM [dbo].[Answers] A INNER JOIN dbo.CountryStates CS ON A.Id = CS.StateId AND CS.CountryId = 46 AND A.Disabled = 0 ORDER BY Position, Code ASC
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using fluent api?

Comment: Yes I'm using fluent API

Comment: OK so you can solve your issue using Include for query, can you show configuration for model and your linq query?

Comment: Please post your `Country` and `State` models. Also the configuration for the above classes.

Comment: I don't have Country and State model. Both of them are stored in the Answer Model. Click on the link bellow the Answer model.

Comment: It is not possible to define relationship because the way data is modelled is complex enough to be part of a direct referential constraint. In CountryState, CountryId takes value from Answer.Id when Answer.QuestionId is 1 but StateId takes value from Answer.Id when Answer.QuestionId is 2. Such conditional constraints are not possible in relational database upto my knowledge. If you can define referential constraints in database for model then I can write EF relationships for you.